# What kind of encryption function is also used for decryption?

Tags: encryption, terminology

Is there a name for the particular type of encryption algorithm or function which is the same algorithm or function used for decryption?  This is a vocabulary question, because I'm largely unfamiliar with the terminology of encryption.  Expressed mathematically, if f(x) is an encryption algorithm and f(f(x))=x, what type of encryption algorithm is it.  An example would be a cipher that converts A to Z, B to Y, C to X, ..., X to C, Y to B, Z to A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to software development. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand correctly what you mean by the “of encryption function is also used for decryption” (you get the open-text from the cipher-text by encrypting it again) the simplest of such function is One-Time Pad – an encryption technique that cannot be cracked, but requires the use of a one-time pre-shared key the same size, as the message being encrypted.

The key have to be truly random data.

The sender, Alice should transfer the key to Bob securely in advance.
Then, later, when Alice want to send encrypted message to Bob, she just applies "exclusive or" logical operation (XOR) between the message and the key to get the cipher text.

Bob then applies XOR again between the ciphertext and the key to get the decrypted message.

First described by Frank Miller in 1882 the one-time pad was re-invented in 1917. On July 22, 1919, U.S. Patent 1,310,719 was issued to Gilbert S. Vernam for the XOR operation used for the encryption of a one-time pad.

If Alice and Bob exchange in total 100 kilobytes of messages, they need a key of the same total size - 100 kilobytes - transmitted securely in advance, because, as I said, they key data may not be reused.

Another example of encryption function is also used for decryption, is any a stream cipher function, like RC4.

By means of stream ciphers, Alice and Bob can generate long keys used for XOR without the need to transmit them in their entire size. They only transmit a short key which will be used to generate a sequence for the long key used for XOR. Such chippers are called Stream Ciphers. Unlike One-Time-Pad which is really unbreakable, the Stream Ciphers, since they use a key much shorter than the message, can be broken, theoretically and sometimes practically.

Not all symmetric-key algorithms are a function that can be used both for encryption and decryption. For example, DES has separate functions for encryption and decryption. You will not get the open-text from the cipher-text by encrypting it again with DES.

Comment: Strictly speaking, RC4 doesn't qualify because the IV is added during encryption and removed during decryption, so f(f(x)) ≠ x. But the same would apply to any probabilistic cipher.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage A stream function per se doesn't know anything about IV, it just generates a sequence of bits. A higher level protocol may deal with all that. Traditional stream ciphers such as RC4 do not support an explicit IV as input.